# MVC, Swing, Observer Pattern - Updating a Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, observer-pattern

I am new to Swing. I am using the MVC architecture. I am unsure how to set up the observer pattern so that I can refresh a JTable whenever new data is entered. My model consists of an Immunization class, and a Visit class, along with a mock patient. A patient has a list of visits and a visit has a list of Immunizations given during that visit. Thus, I have 3 classes - A JFrame Main class called MainFrame, and 2 components - An ImmunizationPanel JPanel, and another panel that creates a JSelectBox.

The Idea is to start the main frame and load the two components, which will show an empty Jtable and a list of Immunizations to choose from in a drop down box. At this point the UI is very simple. The user is to click the SelectBox and then hit enter and it should update the Jtable with the value chosen in the SelectBox.

I have a few Controllers that provide the business logic. My question is, What classes do I make observer and observable? A problem I am running into is that MainFrame already extends JFrame, so it cannot also extend Observable. So should I only be using Observable and Observer in my controllers? At this point my table is updating only after the program is restarted and it loads the data at run time.

I can provide code if anyone needs to see it, but my question isn't about the code per se, it is about where to extend Observable and Observer. Do you use it in the View, in the model, or the controllers?

Thanks.

Comment: I know that this really isn't an answer to your question, but I'd like to suggest that you take a look at Griffon. It's an MVC framework for desktop apps in Groovy (which is a Java derivitave). Having just written a rather large Swing application with it, I can say that it made things a whole lot easier. Particularly model/view bindings and notifications. I don't think I'd ever write a straight-up Swing app in Java again.

Comment: welcome to Swing :-) Be sure to read some basic articles about Swing architecture, f.i. in those referenced in the swing tag wiki (aka: the _info_ tab)

Comment: Your table model is responsible for notifying the table that its contents has changed. IMHO, I'd set up a table model that has mutable properties (add/update/delete) and call these as required. Once you've updated the model, I'd fire the appropriate event required to update the table. How you go about updating to model will come down a lot to how you want to construct the architecture of yr application. You could call directly into the model (from the controller) or create some intermediate model of your own

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I ended up Using a TableModel and then changing that table model, and that seemed to work to update the table.